# Can field lines be ever parallel?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

I know that this question is not really relevant , but it's still troubling me and that's why I am asking it out of curiosity. I wonder whether it is theoretically possible for field lines to be parallel (and separated by a finite distance) somewhere due to some charge configuration.

Also, I feel this question is not completely useless as it poses a question on existence of uniform electric which I doubt exist as maybe I don't fully know what they mean. So I would also know about uniform electric fields precisely and my previous question would be required to understand this.

So, I would like to have mathematical arguments in favour or against both the questions. I myself am unable to find configurations where electric field lines are parallel and intuitively feel that their existence is not possible and hold a similar view about uniform electric fields.

Thanks.

Comment: How about a parallel-plate capacitor?

Comment: @Qmechanic I'm not aware about them, so I'll read about this . Thanks.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think there also the field lines will not be parallel as they are parallel if uniform charge density is assumed which strictly speaking is only accurate. What I want is something with discrete charges as they are more close to reality, though less convenient. Also, I would like to know about a uniform field as I am having difficulty in understanding what we mean by it.